# Cannot update UEFI firmware on Dell Latitude 5401 with snap or fwupdmgr. Cannot find Latitude_5X01_Precision_3541_1.26.0.cab in archive

Tags: updates, uefi, dell, fwupd

I am using:

```
Distributor ID:  Ubuntu
Description:  Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:  22.04
Codename:  jammy

starcat@normandy:~/Загрузки$ fwupdmgr --version 
runtime   org.freedesktop.fwupd         1.7.9
runtime   com.dell.libsmbios            2.4
compile   org.freedesktop.gusb          0.3.10
compile   com.hughsie.libjcat           0.1.9
runtime   org.kernel                    6.2.0-26-generic
compile   org.freedesktop.fwupd         1.7.9
runtime   org.freedesktop.gusb          0.3.10
```

Yesterday snap has showed that there is an update, but when I try to apply it, an error occurs.

```
"cannot find Latitude_5X01_Precision_3541_1.26.0.cab in archive"
```

From the console you can see that he even downloads it, but then falls into the same error.
The file itself is on the LVFS website. And you can download it by hand.
But I want to understand why the system itself cannot do this.

```
starcat@normandy:~/Загрузки$ sudo fwupdmgr update 
Devices with no available firmware updates: 
 • 0000:00:1f.5
 • TPM 2.0
 • UEFI dbx
Devices with the latest available firmware version:
 • Micron 2200S NVMe 256GB
╔══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Upgrade System Firmware from 1.25.0 to 1.26.0?                               ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ This stable release fixes the following issues:                              ║
║                                                                              ║
║ • This release contains security updates as disclosed in the Dell            ║
║ Security Advisories.                                                         ║
║                                                                              ║
║ Latitude 5401 must remain plugged into a power source for the duration of    ║
║ the update to avoid damage.                                                  ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝

Perform operation? [Y|n]: y
Downloading…             [***************************************]
Downloading…             [***************************************]
cannot find Latitude_5X01_Precision_3541_1.26.0.cab in archive
```

UPD.
I think that not related to Ubuntu. Something wrong with the archive itself.

I've downloaded current and previous versions from LVFS site. And offline "get-details" on file gives the save error regardless of OS where I have checked it.

But previous version is showing details without problems.

P.S. "Device was not found" it's because I've made this check on other device. But that not important in this question.

=================================================

```
fwupdmgr get-details 75716e9132fdbe86671f4853e08e6d947c19b04f771071b56b8978c0f133d2cd-Latitude_5X01_Precision_3541_1.26.0.cab 
Распаковка…              [     \                                 ]cannot find Latitude_5X01_Precision_3541_1.26.0.cab in archive
```

=================================================

```
fwupdmgr get-details 781018825d53f6837a582a66afb3e5fed7061c342c7653eaaa547c61b2aaff3f-Latitude_5X01_Precision_3541_1.24.0.cab 
Распаковка…              [***************************************]
To be filled by O.E.M.
│
└─Unknown Device:
  │   Description:        
  │   Updating the system firmware improves performance.
  │   Update Error:       Device was not found
  │   GUID:               0eecff0c-95b8-4ade-9717-8f4f3edc9e09
  │   Device Flags:       • Supported on remote server
  │ 
  └─Latitude 5X01/Precision 3541:
        New version:      0x11800
        Remote ID:        lvfs
        Summary:          Firmware for the Dell Latitude 5X01/Precision 3541
        License:          Proprietary
        Size:             23,8 MB
        Urgency:          Critical
        Update Message:   Do not turn off your computer or remove the AC adapter while the update is in progress.
        Release Flags:    • Trusted payload
                          • Trusted metadata
        Description:      
        This stable release fixes the following issues:
        
        Some new functionality has also been added:
        
        • Firmware updates to address security vulnerabilities including (Common Vulnerabilities and Exposures - CVE)

=================================================

fwupdmgr get-details 58b06e2b43e5db6fe556c084f0d03d40b3476810eae3b2ae1e344e562a35a647-Latitude_5X01_Precision_3541_1.25.0.cab 
Распаковка…              [***************************************]
To be filled by O.E.M.
│
└─Unknown Device:
  │   Description:        
  │   Updating the system firmware improves performance.
  │   Update Error:       Device was not found
  │   GUID:               0eecff0c-95b8-4ade-9717-8f4f3edc9e09
  │   Device Flags:       • Supported on remote server
  │ 
  └─Latitude 5X01/Precision 3541:
        New version:      0x11900
        Remote ID:        lvfs
        Summary:          Firmware for the Dell Latitude 5X01/Precision 3541
        License:          Proprietary
        Size:             23,8 MB
        Urgency:          Critical
        Update Message:   Do not turn off your computer or remove the AC adapter while the update is in progress.
        Release Flags:    • Trusted payload
                          • Trusted metadata
        Description:      
        This stable release fixes the following issues:
        
        • This release contains security updates as disclosed in the Dell Security Advisories .
  =================================================
```

On the other hand archove is readeble with usual cabextract.

```
cabextract -t 75716e9132fdbe86671f4853e08e6d947c19b04f771071b56b8978c0f133d2cd-Latitude_5X01_Precision_3541_1.26.0.cab 
Testing cabinet: 75716e9132fdbe86671f4853e08e6d947c19b04f771071b56b8978c0f133d2cd-Latitude_5X01_Precision_3541_1.26.0.cab
  README.txt  OK                               47dec8984e330f7e490f614f9231d571
  catalog.cat  OK                              eaa6cd7d1aac6a9485a5c0ddf15c59db
  firmware.bin  OK                             66e17ddb2fb9f65ab2c1abf9e6ee4eec
  firmware.bin.asc  OK                         727c51bb652c4a7f39ea1b4f3c779a1e
  firmware.inf  OK                             817f4bdbab1ecaad6bab0d2b593a843b
  firmware.jcat  OK                            be01d4258e5a544ba479cfd27c4055dc
  firmware.metainfo.xml  OK                    9c7b14fc1c07f88c40f7d5821da12e58

All done, no errors.
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolved.
The reason for the failure was in the archive itself. Was fixed by lvfs maintainer